# Problems with checkboxes again asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an updatepanel with a load of checkboxes in, and outside of the panel I have a "check all" checkbox.

However I cannot get it to work. I set it as a trigger, with the checkedchanged event. The code runs, and sets all the checked values to true... but this is not reflected on the page.

I eventually found that the updatepanel also runs its "load" event, which redraws all the components... and I figured its checking them in the first trigger, and redrawing them all in the second thus overwriting it.

So I put an if statement in - if the asyncpostbacktrigger is the checkbox, dont bother redrawing all the controls (return;). The result of this though is that all the controls disappear! I guess updatepanels automatically empty themselves when they postback.

So my next attempt was, when the updatepanel redraws, if the trigger is the checkbox, set the value of all the checkboxes to true. Doesn't work. It hits the line that sets them to true, but when it's finished, they are not true.

I can't understand how this is possible and it's driving me nuts...!

Comment: Can you share the code? Providing the aspx and codebehind would be very helpful.

Comment: do you actually requires a postback ? Can't you simply update it with a simple javascript code (jquery may help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 hours of debugging... fixed it. Checkboxes didn't have an ID which broke it. Bummer!